# Python Sql Outputs

Tags: sql, output

When running the following code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example3.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name;
''') 
print c.fetchall()  

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The results are shown are in tuples.

```
[(u'courses',),(u'gradingscheme',),(u'students',),(u'topstudent',)]
```

I want to be able to show the results in a column format instead. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you show how the results are displayed?

Comment: @Utsav I added the results I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no sqlite programmer but you might try something like

```
#print c.fetchall() 
row = c.fetchall()
for r in row: print r
```